# Creating a list in SQL and iterating through the list after the FROM line

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to access some table like Toyota_Corolla, Toyota_Camry, Toyota_Prius, Toyota_Rav4

Instead of typing out multiple SELECT statements like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Toyota_Corolla;
SELECT * FROM Toyota_Camry;
SELECT * FROM Toyota_Prius;
SELECT * FROM Toyota_Rav4;
```

Is there a way to create a list of strings like ['Corolla', 'Camry', 'Prius', Rav4'] and iterate through the list after the `FROM` line to something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM 'Toyota_'` + 'some loop to iterate the list of car model'
```

I know for my example, it's easier to just type out the whole thing, but what about the situation when Toyota has hundred of models?

This is MS SQL Server DBMS

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info

Answer (score 1):

No.  First, you should fix your data model so you have a single table with an additional column for the Toyota model.  That is the right way to store the data.

With the data you have, you can emulate this with a view:

```
create view vw_toyota as
    select 'Corolla' as toyota_model, t.* from Toyota_Corolla t union all
    select 'Camry' as toyota_model, t.* from Toyota_Camry t union all
    select 'Prius' as toyota_model, t.* from Toyota_Prius t union all
    select 'Rav4' as toyota_model, t.* from Toyota_Rav4 t;
```

This also adds the source table information.

And then do:

```
select *
from vw_toyota;
```